# The final death of meta-tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion, meta-tags

It did happen on SO, SU and SF: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/.

So shall we follow? [beginner](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) is the most used tag here...

**Update:** Done. No more [beginner](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) and [subjective](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective).

Comment: I also did removed "introductory" and "layman" tags. These meta tags are now synonyms for "beginner", so we just need to delete the "beginner" tag every now and again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to agree with Jeff. Some of the posts tagged "beginner" are not exactly easy questions. Tagging is most useful when you want to search for answers on a particular topic. Anyone searching "beginner" is not going to find the results very useful.

Comment: I agree; it was mainly useful as a title supplement rather than a search query.

Answer (score 3):

I am not in favor of a "beginner" tag (nor an "advanced" or "intermediate" tag for that matter). I think the use will be inconsistent--some people, perhaps new users might use the tag as a shorthand for "pardon my ignorance, but...." while the same question by someone who has an active history on this Site is probably not interested in seeing their tag profile with a whole bunch of beginner tags and so they stay away from them--likewise, for answering them.

Aside from that, some of the best answers i've seen on this Site are to questions that were or should have been tagged 'beginner'--the OP might have been a beginner, but clearly it was not a beginner who answered it. So why have a tag attached to that thread that is a synonym for "easy?"