# Do we need a soft question tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

I have just asked [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41600/930) that I think would qualify on http://math.stackexchange.com as a [soft question](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/soft-question/info) (it relates to general methods for survey data).

Would it be worth creating a "soft question" tag for such cases?

I think that such questions have value, but they won't necessarily get a formula or theorem as their answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so since its tag excerpt (as it reads on math.se) may suggest endless discussion or personal opinion, with no accepted answer, which does not fit well with QAs sites like this. We also have the [community-owned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/150510) option.

Besides, you may well end up with an acceptable answer for this particular question.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes I think I will on this question, maybe it is not as useful as I thought.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @chl's good answer, it's worth noting that such a tag would be a (so-called) 'meta tag'.  (A *meta tag* is a tag about a property of the question, rather than categorizing its content; the only meta tag left is [homework](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework).)  Stack Exchange explicitly discourages meta tags.  You can read the official statement here: [The death of meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and about it's adoption on CV here: [the-final-death-of-meta-tags](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/).